# How can I explain() an upsert in MongoDB to see if indexes are used?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, insert, indexing, upsert

When code changes, a quick way that tells me if indexes are still proper for `find()` statements is (`nodejs`)

```
        collection.find(query).explain(function(err, explaination) {
            console.log('MongoDebug: ' + explaination.cursor);
        });
```

If the cursor is of type `BtreeCursor`, indexes are used.

How do I check this when using `insert()` with `upsert: true`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`explain()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/) is a function on the cursor and is not available on inserts. There's also a [`$explain`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/meta/explain/) query modifier, but it's still a *query* modifier.

However, there's a big load of work filed as `explain 2.0`, one of the subtasks is to provide [`explain()` for updates - SERVER-14101](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-14101). That's listed as fixed in version 2.7.7.

As a note, performing explain for every operation might be a bad idea, because it forces MongoDB to reevaluate query plans all the time, thereby increasing the server load on the database.

You can use the [integrated profiler](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/) and [`db.currentOp()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.currentOp/) to analyze performance of non-query operations for now, but the insights are limited. Try a simple `find().explain()` for manual optimization, the indexes used should be the same.